# Magento - Create form that places an order?

Tags: php, magento

My Question is:
Is it possible to create a form in Magento that creates an order in the Backend?

We want to send catalogs to customers who are sending us a request by our contact form.

But it would be easier for our process to directly place an order for this request.

Thx so far ur help!

Answer (score 0):

You could create your order form, then create your order programmatically (see [Programmatically create order in Magento](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/) or use magento api (see [Magento API - Mage_Checkout](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.html#content)).

However, if you products have a lot of custom options, then it may get complex to get the various option ids